# Low quality of realtime audio/video calls. Route such traffic through a separate WAN connection?

Tags: routing, qos, isp

We have problems with the quality of audio/video calls in our office. We get much better quality using mobile LTE connection than our fiber link. LTE connection always goes HD, but the fiber connection almost always gets stuck at lower quality.

Our ISP provides us 60 Mbit/s download and 16 Mbit/s of upload. Average latency is around 20ms and jitter seems to be 10ms. They say everything seems to be fine, but our calls quality is bad. We've also upgraded our bandwidth (we had 30/8), but it didn't help. Most of the time we have a single call running.

Since it's the only ISP in our office location, we can't change it. So I see 2 options. First is that it's something in our network. But we tested it and there's no packet loss, or significant latency, or jitter at the path to our router, so it seems unlikely. Second is that it's something in the ISP's network or they have low QoS offered from the backbone. Since we can't do much about it, we'd like to set up a separate mobile LTE connection that will be used for video/audio calls. We mostly use Skype, Hangouts, Uberconferece or Gotomeeting. Is there a network solution that automatically route such traffic through a separate WAN connection? It seems that we can't know the IP addresses used by these services so we can't do that using routing tables. We're also thinking about setting up a separate WiFi network for the calls, but we're afraid that when people finish the call, they will stay on the network designated for calls and make it congested by regular web traffic. Ideally, we'd like people to be automatically switched back to the other network when the call finishes. Alternatively, some kind of pop up could show up on their computer asking if they require to stay on the wifi network for calls if they stay connected for more than 30 mins for example. Is there a good solution for such a problem?

Comment: The ISP has no QoS priority what so ever?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Doesn't the ISP of your fiber connection got any QoS classes in their MPLS/WAN topology? Sounds improbably.

Comment: I don't know that since I don't know their internal network topology. I think I can ask, but I'm not sure how it could help.

Comment: Well, if they were to use QoS, you can prioritize your traffic in the best possible classes in order for it to be transported faster and with higher quality hence removing the problems you are experiencing. If you know their priority classes you can choose to remark your traffic and send it to the ISP priority queues.

Comment: OK, understood now. That would be great - I'll check it. So you suggest talking to the ISP about marking our traffic as higher priority, right? I understand that I can't do that on my own.

Comment: It may not be just your ISP that is the problem. The Internet is just the ISPs connecting to each other in any way they want. Your traffic may pass through several different ISPs on its way to its destination. You may be able to negotiate some QoS agreement with your ISP, but your QoS policies and markings will not be honored across the Internet.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought. OK, I'll try to negotiate it. Assuming I can't get anything more from my ISP, is there a good solution to route such traffic through a different WAN connection?

Comment: That will depend on your router model. You may be able to set up PBR.

Comment: I'm open to change my router. I'll look for PBR enabled routers then. Thanks!